# How to change the internal wlan in laptops/netbooks?

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, laptop, upgrade, netbook

as I use mostly linux, I'm trying to customise my netbook and my wlan is my only rock in the path of a fully open source supported netbook ... *Plug and play in linux*

Here's what I need to swap/switch :
Toshiba Satellite A300 Wlan (Intel) <---> Emachines eM350 Wlan (broadcom-wl)

Comment: Do you want to physically swap the hardware or spoof drivers or what?  Please be more specific.

Comment: swap the hardware ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a miniPCI card under the keyboard. Just unplug the antenna, remove the old card, and put the new one in.

Here's an image of what a miniPCI card looks like:

[image]

Comment: Do I can have an issue at reboot without reinstalling linux ?

Does photos or videos that show how to do it exist ?

Comment: You won't need to reinstall Linux. My apologies on the location, though. In the A300/A305, it's under the keyboard. take a look at page 2 of: http://www.irisvista.com/tech/laptops/Toshiba-Satellite-A305/laptop-disassembly-process-1.htm